# How to store string data in BIGSQL table with length greater than VARCHAR(32k)

Tags: hadoop, hive, db2, bigdata, bigsql

The data beyond 32762 characters is getting truncated when I am loading the data in my BigSQL table. My table definition is as below :

CREATE hadoop TABLE schema_name.table_name
(
  column1 VARCHAR(50),
  column2 INTEGER,
  column3 STRING,
  loaddate TIMESTAMP
)
STORED AS PARQUET;

The for column3 is getting truncated.
Is there a way to store the full data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the CLOB is the answer you're looking for

Comment: I had used the same but it gave me an error. Unfortunately BigSQL Hadoop table doesn't support CLOB datatype.